# como configurar correctamente Guzzle con symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony2, http

Buen día.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es tener el cliente con php, por lo cual decidí usar esta librería(Guzzle), que me permite consumir servicios web tipo rest desde php.

Ya seguí la documentación pero me sale este error:

> Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "GuzzleHttp". Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client", "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client", "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client", "Solarium\Client" or "Solarium\Core\Client\Client"?"

La librería ya la descargue con composer, ya agregue el "use GuzzleHttp\Client" pero nada.

También la agregué al AppKernel.php de esta manera:

```
new EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\GuzzleBundle()
```

Pero cuando hago esto me sale este error:

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 42:
> Attempted to load class "GuzzleBundle" from namespace "EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle".
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Que es lo que me falta?
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in your controller this ligne :

use  \Bundle\GuzzleBundle\Entity\Client;

use \Bundle\GuzzleBundle\Form\ClientType;

Comment: Hola @Ahmed. Estamos en el sitio en español. Considera utilizar español para el contenido principal de tus publicaciones.